# Can`t sending file from android to php if (setChunkedStreamingMode )

Tags: php, android

Trying to send large file from android to php, I can send small size ( up to 1 mp)
I was looking around for solution and  "setChunkedStreamingMode" show up
when I set the connection.setconnection(1024) I cant send any file even the small size. getting PHP echo "cannot uploading the file!!!!"
this is android code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {



    uploadFileToServer("path","http://"");
    downloadFileFromServer("path","http://"");
}

/**
 * This function upload the large file to server with other POST values.
 * @param filename
 * @param targetUrl
 * @return
 */
public static String uploadFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
    String response = "error";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = filename;
    String urlServer = targetUrl;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    //String path = filename;
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        //connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", filename);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        String token = "anyvalye";
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Token\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + token.length() + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(token + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


        String taskId = "anyvalue";
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"TaskID\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + taskId.length() + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(taskId + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        String connstr = null;
       connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;

        outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        System.out.println("Image length " + bytesAvailable + "");
        try {
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                try {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "outofmemoryerror";
                    return response;
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "error";
            return response;
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println("Server Response Code " + " " + serverResponseCode);
        System.out.println("Server Response Message "+ serverResponseMessage);

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            response = "true";
        }else
        {
            response = "false";
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();

        connection.getInputStream();
        //for android InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

        int ch;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
            b.append( (char)ch );
        }

        String responseString = b.toString();
        System.out.println("response string is" + responseString); //Here is the actual output

        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Exception handling
        response = "error";
        System.out.println("Send file Exception" + ex.getMessage() + "");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}

/**
 * This function download the large files from the server
 * @param filename
 * @param urlString
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void downloadFileFromServer(String filename, String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
        {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
                in.close();
        if (fout != null)
                fout.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}

and this is PHP code

> ```
> <?php
> $target_path = "uploads/";
> /* Add the original filename to our target path.
> Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
> $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
> if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
>     echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
>     " uploaded.";
> } else{
>     echo "cannot uploading the file!!!!  ";
>     echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
>     echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
> }
> ?>
> ```

any help ?
thanks

Comment: where is the previous answers and links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using this PHP code, it's working fine for me **

```
public void uploadFile() {
String charset = "UTF-8";
File[] uploadFileArray = new File[mediaList.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
    uploadFileArray[i] = new File(mediaList.get(i).getMediaPath());
}

try {
    MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(upLoadServerUri, charset);

    for (int i = 0; i < mediaList.size(); i++) {
        if (isImage)) {
            multipart.addFilePart("image_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
        } 
        else if (isVideo) {
            multipart.addFilePart("video_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
        } 
        else if (isAudio) {
            multipart.addFilePart("audio_doc[]", uploadFileArray[i]);
        }
    }

    List<String> responseUploadDocument = multipart.finish();
    System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

    for (String line : responseUploadDocument) {
        System.out.println(line);
        responseUploadDocumentString = line;
    }

    if (responseUploadDocumentString != null) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseUploadDocumentString);
        statusUploadDoc = jsonObj.getString("status");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}